# JQuery calling json data for google visualization map won't use json values in $.each

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, google-visualization, each

Json:
    `[{"latitude":"42.658673","longitude":"-73.810479","place":"Bethany Reformed Church"}]`

Full function:
    `google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["map"]});`

```
    $(function() {
     // when document loads, grab the json
     $.getJSON('places.json', function(data) {
         // once grabbed, we run this callback

         // setup the new map and its variables
         var meetings = new google.visualization.DataTable();
             meetings.addRows(data.length);  // length gives us the number of results in our returned data
             meetings.addColumn('number', 'latitude');
             meetings.addColumn('number', 'longitude');
             meetings.addColumn('string', 'place');

         // now we need to build the map data, loop over each result
         $.each(data, function(i,v) {
             // set the values for both the location and place
             alert(i + ":" + v.latitude + ":" + v.longitude + ":" + v.place);
             // The alert displays the correct values
             meetings.setValue(i, 0, v.latitude);
             meetings.setValue(i, 1, v.longitude);
             meetings.setValue(i, 2, v.place);
             //the code stalls and nothing else gets executed
         });
         // finally, create the map!
         var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
         map.draw(meetings, {showTip: true, mapType: 'normal'});

     });
   });
```

If I alert() the json values inside the $.each, they are correct, but the code stalls when the json values are in meetings.setValue(). I came to this conclusion because if I put an alert after the meetings.setValues, nothing pops up.

Output of alert:

```
0:42.658673:-73.810479:Bethany Reformed Church
```

If I hard code the actual locations in meetings.setValue(), it maps the location correctly.

Like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,v) {
             // this maps the location correctly
             meetings.setValue(i, 0, 42.658673);
             meetings.setValue(i, 1, -73.810479);
             meetings.setValue(i, 2, 'Bethany Reformed Church');
 });
```

Why does the code seem to stall in the $.each when the json variables are used?

I have been using this as a guide: [Using jQuery, JSON and Google’s Visualization Geo API Together](http://wesbos.com/jquery-json-google-visualization-api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hardcode it you're using numbers:

```
setValue(i, 0, 42.658673);
```

but your JSON has strings:

```
"longitude":"-73.810479"
```

So either try changing the JSON to send numbers:

```
"longitude":-73.810479
```

or convert the strings to numbers before you send them to `setValue`:

```
meetings.setValue(i, 0, +v.latitude);
meetings.setValue(i, 1, +v.longitude);
```

The unary `+` will convert the string to a number. For a more explicit conversion, use the `Number` constructor (but called without `new`).

```
meetings.setValue(i, 0, Number(v.latitude));
meetings.setValue(i, 1, Number(v.longitude));
```